# XSL won't work with single item

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm  an xsl noob as will soon be evident. I have a report that works well when there are multiple nodes but when the XML contains a single node it won't display the values. By single node I mean 1 entry that is 1 row in the report. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="UserName">Will.Bean</Property>
    <Property Name="IP_Address">99.99.99.99</Property>
    <Property Name="FailureReason">%%2313</Property>
    <Property Name="WorkstationName">OKC-CL6</Property>
    <Property Name="SubStatus">Bad Password.</Property>
    <Property Name="Status">Unknown user name or bad password.</Property>
    <Property Name="DomainName">AcmeOrg</Property>
    <Property Name="Date">5/27/2017 5:16:48 AM</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

The XSL (some style removed for brevity) that I use to display this, and which works fine with > 1 entries, follows. Thank you for looking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Objects/Object">
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://acme.com/sp/SiteAssets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://acme.com/sp/SiteAssets/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
table.sorttable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(defaultSorter);
        function defaultSorter() {
            $("#lockouts").tablesorter();
        }
</script>
</head>
    <body>

<table id="lockouts" class="sorttable">
<thead>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
<th>Date</th>
<th>Domain</th>
<th>User</th>
<th>IP_Address</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>SubStatus</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Property"/>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr><td>Updated every 30 minutes</td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Property">
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Date']"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Domain']"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='UserName']"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='IP_Address']"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Status']"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='SubStatus']"/></td>       
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `match="Property"` and `select="Property[@Name='Date']"` can't work with your input as inside the template the matched `Property` element is the context node and it doesn't have any `Property` child elements you are trying to select. You haven't shown the sample your code works with, nor have you explained which elements in your XML you want to map to HTML table rows and which to cells.

Comment: hi Martin. It looks like the issue is the way the XML is being written using the powershell ConvertTo-xml method with a depth equal to 1. upon reexamination of the xml output a single entry is missing the encasing Property tags. I'll show myself out.